# How do I determine if my Selenium script was able to log in?

Tags: python, selenium, if-statement, testing

How can I make this selenium script know if it was able to log in or not? Currently I am using `is_displayed()` to see if the login form is still on the page. Is there a better way?

```
driver.find_element_by_id("uname").send_keys("admin")
driver.find_element_by_id("pwd").send_keys("admin")
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="login_form"]/div/button').click()

# below xpath is code for invalid user id or password message
if driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="login_form"]/div[1]').is_displayed():
    output=open("OutputAdmin","w+")
    output.write("Login unsuccessful")
    output.close()
else:
    output = open("OutputAdmin", "w+")
    output.write("Login successful")
    output.close()
driver.quit()
```

Now if user id or password is incorrect it is working fine but if they are correct it doesn't execute else code.

Comment: comments in python use the `#`

Comment: ok that was for you guys to explain that it was xpath of error message its not present in the code..

Answer (score 0):

```
try:
    LoginFailMessage = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="login_form"]/div[1]')
    if LoginFailMessage.is_displayed():
        output=open("OutputAdmin","w+")
        output.write("Login unsuccessful")
        output.close()
except:
    output = open("OutputAdmin", "w+")
    output.write("Login successful")
    output.close()
```

i have solved the issue.thanks to those who tried to solve it.